# Spring-Kafka 2.1.3.release compatibility with apache-kafka-2.8.1 client

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My project is built with Spring boot 1.5.10.release. We want to migrate to Apache Kafka 2.8.1 from Apache Kafka 2.11.x. We are currently using Spring-kafka 2.1.3. Can we connect the kafka without changing the Spring-kafka version ?

Comment: you can inject apache kafka version in your pom

Answer (score 0):

That version is totally out of date and is no longer supported.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

The oldest supported OSS version is 2.7.10.

I doubt such an old version will work with recent clients, especially if you are using the embedded broker for testing.